# How to match values from 2 lists in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to create a filter based varchar column and the value could have one or more comma separated strings like this

> ```
>   col
> a 12
> b 489
> c 456,486
> d 489,45,789
> ```

if the entry was `489` the returned value should be `b and d` 
if the entry was `45,489` the returned value should be `d` 
regardless of values order , this column is a foreign key column .
how to do this in oracle ?

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I know that but it was not my choice to do that , I recently got employed for this job and the database was created before 7 years I guess .@jarlh

Comment: The value you're searching for is passed as a CSV string too, and you need tt ignore the order they're in? Or are you passed a collection of values? Do they even need to be contiguous (so should '45,489' also match '1,489,2,45,3...')?

Comment: yes it should match '1,489,2,45,3...'  with ignoring the order because the value entered from user and it could be in any order @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the issues with the data model, if you have to compare the contents of two CSV strings while ignoring the order the elements appear you'll need to split at least one of them up into its constiuent parts.

This builds on @Tim's `like` comparison by splitting the user-supplied value into separate values in a CTE, joining that to your real table using the `like` mechanism, and then counting how many matches there were.

```
with cte (val, cnt) as (
  select regexp_substr('45,489', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1),
    regexp_count('45,489', ',') + 1
  from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count('45,489', ',') + 1
)
select t.id, t.col
from your_table t
join cte on ',' || t.col || ',' like '%,' || cte.val || ',%'
group by t.id, t.col
having count(cte.val) = max(cte.cnt)
```

It only returns rows where the number of joined values matches the count of joined values.

Quick demo with sample data in another CTE:

```
with your_table (id, col) as (
            select 'a', '12' from dual
  union all select 'b', '489' from dual
  union all select 'c', '456,486' from dual
  union all select 'd', '489,45,789' from dual
  union all select 'e', '1,489,2,45,3' from dual
  union all select 'f', '1,489,2,45,3,489' from dual
),
cte (val, cnt) as (
  select regexp_substr('45,489', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1),
    regexp_count('45,489', ',') + 1
  from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count('45,489', ',') + 1
)
select t.id, t.col
from your_table t
join cte on ',' || t.col || ',' like '%,' || cte.val || ',%'
group by t.id, t.col
having count(cte.val) = max(cte.cnt);

ID COL                
-- -------------------
f  1,489,2,45,3,489,45
d  489,45,789         
e  1,489,2,45,3
```

Comment: Thank you so much .

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LIKE` along with some concatenation tricks:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE ',' || id || ',' LIKE '%,489,%';
```

But your current design is seriously suboptimal, because you are storing comma separated values in the `id` column.  This greatly limits Oracle's ability to filter that column.  Instead, you should try to get each `id` value onto a separate row.

Note: This answer only works for searching for a single value against your `id` CSV.  If you need to search more than one value at the same time, you would have to duplicate the logic in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: if the value in like keyword was `LIKE '%45,489,%'; ` there will be no return value .. am I right ??

Comment: I guess you didn't bother to read my answer at all.  **DON'T** try to search a comma separated string against another CSV string.  _Normalize_ your data!

Comment: I've read your answer , its my fault that I didn't mention that this column is a foreign key column , and the database I'm working on has been created by someone else .. and I'm forced to work with it this way ..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the values as strings, store it as a nested table and you can use the `SUBMULTISET` operator:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(3,0)
/

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  name CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ids intlist
) NESTED TABLE ids STORE AS table_name__ids;

INSERT INTO table_name ( name, ids )
SELECT 'a', intlist( 12 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', intlist( 489 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', intlist( 456, 486 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', intlist( 489, 45, 789 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  intlist( 489 ) SUBMULTISET OF ids;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME
----
b
d
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  intlist( 45, 489 ) SUBMULTISET OF ids;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME
----
d
```

---

If you must store the values as strings then you can create a function to convert the string to a collection and use the same technique:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(3,0)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitNumberList(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN INTLIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       INTLIST := INTLIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ) );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  name CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ids  VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( name, ids )
SELECT 'a', '12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', '489' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', '456,486' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', '489,45,789' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  splitNumberList( '489' ) SUBMULTISET OF splitNumberList( ids );
```

**Output**:

```
NAME
----
b
d
```

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  splitNumberList( '45,489' ) SUBMULTISET OF splitNumberList( ids );
```

**Output**:

```
NAME
----
d
```